# svn list sometimes doesn't work on GitHub repositories

Tags: git, github, svn

I'm using `svn list` to obtain a list of files in a subdirectory in a GitHub repository .  Sometimes the command works, but often it fails.  The subdirectory has 1020 files in it.  Here is the exact command

`svn list https://github.com/dchassin/gridlabd-weather/branches/master/US/`. (The repo is public, so anyone should be able to do it.)  If I try the command on another directory in the same repo, e.g., `svn list https://github.com/dchassin/gridlabd-weather/branches/master/utilities/`, then it works ok.  I'm guessing this has to do with how many files are in the folder.

Any ideas on what's wrong and what to do about it?  Thanks.

Comment: I should have specified that the error message is `svn: E160016: Can't get entries of non-directory`.

Comment: Here's an interesting tidbit: if I run `svn list -rHEAD https://github.com/dchassin/gridlabd-weather/branches/master/US/` I get the error `svn: E160016...`. But if I issue the command `svn list -r1 https://github.com/dchassin/gridlabd-weather/branches/master/US/` it works ok. Looks to me like a GitHub problem.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that GitHub restricts the listing of only 1000 Files and leaves the other files out .

[image: 1000 Files Limit]

So the `svn list` commands errors out when it is run on this directory. There is not much that you can do about it.

Comment: I tried the following command to see if the error message was misleading: `time svn --config-option=servers:global:http-timeout=60 list https://github.com/dchassin/gridlabd-weather/branches/master/US/` and got the following result: `svn: E160016: Can't get entries of non-directory

real 0m42.230s
user 0m0.047s
sys 0m0.014s` so I'm assume the timeout isn't the cause. I also tried a timeout of `0` with the same result but I'm using subversion 1.10 and I'm not sure it's using SERF, so I am not sure whether 0 disables it.

Comment: OK some hands on and some googling enlighten's me that GitHub has imposed a limitation of listing only 1000 files per directory , so when a svn list command is executed i think the GitHub Errors out and hence you see an exception . I googled for "Github 1000-file-per-dir"

Comment: I saw the file limit too, but I'm not sure that's the problem.  The limit certainly applies to the web interface, but changing the svn revision allows it work, so the limit doesn't seem to apply to `svn list`.  I tried a range of revisions between 1 and HEAD and it worked up to -r4, then it didn't work for -r5 and -r6.